# Firebase handle unfinished downloads when user closes the app by swiping from overview window

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am downloading an image from firebase to my local storage.

```
final StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child(widget.musicPackData.imageFirebasePath);

await imageRef.writeToFile(File(localPathImage)).future;
```

The code works fine as anyone would expect. The problem is if a user closes my app from the overview window by swiping it while the download is still going on, the download is interrupted and it basically stops. If the download has not finished before the app is killed, it leaves an unfinished corrupted file in the local storage. Since I only want to get this file once and store it in local storage I can not tell if this file is completely downloaded or not. I tried removing the file in AppLifecycleState.detached callback but it seems to be broken so thats not a solution [see here for more info on AppLifecycleState.detached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999854/applifecyclestate-detached-is-not-called).

Is there any way for me to clean this file when an app is killed from the overview window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll typically want to write the file to a temporary filename initially, and then only rename it to its final name once the download completes. That's what Chrome does too for example, which is why you may find `.crdownload` file for aborted downloads.

You can clean up the files when the app is started the next time, by searching for those abandoned partial files.

Comment: Very useful and clever.